# Is the a mechanism in Spring MVC to rename bean for JSON

Tags: json, spring-mvc

is there a way to rename bean properties in a Spring MVC response, I'm using content negotiation and the response is returned is JSON.

For example, if I have a class with field called 'title'

```
public class Entity {

    @XmlAttribute
    private String title;
}
```

in the JSON that is created I would like it to be displayed as so:

```
"entity":{
    "myCompany:title": "this is the title"
}
```

Comment: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/04/jaxb-and-json-via-jettison-namespace.html

Answer (score 0):

<strike>[`@XmlAttribute`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlAttribute.html) annotation has `name` attribute, so I suggest to try with it:-</strike>

```
public class Entity {

    @XmlAttribute(name = "myCompany:title")
    private String title;
}
```

---

**Updated:** My answer looks wrong. Try following:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Entity {

    @XmlElement(name = "myCompany:title")
    private String title;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for updating, I tried that too but it doesn't work either.